# Unable to mount file share if vm is hybrid joined (AD authentication)

Tags: windows, azure, azure-active-directory, active-directory, azure-storage

I have the following setup:

**Azure Virtual Machine**
Hybrid joined (On-Prem AD, AAD joined)

- Access by Host Pool assigned to the AAD user identities
- If I leave from AAD, it requires domain\username + password when launching the desktop (fileshare mount works)
- If its hybrid joined no further authentication is required (mount not working)

**Storage account**
On-prem authentication enabled
My issue is that if the machine is hybrid joined, I'm not able to access the file share with AD authentication. It says "Can't find fileshare xxx Check spelling"

If I leave the AAD and only keep the machine into the on-prem AD the access is working smoothly. We have a requirement that requires the AD authentication, but also the hybrid join to have access to some O365 applications etc. Otherwise I would just go for the on-prem join, but that's not possible.

I guess that Windows is not using the AD credentials when trying to access the share if its hybrid joined?

What am I doing wrong?

- If the machine is only joined to on-prem AD its working
- If its hybrid joined its not working

Comment: How do you mount an Azure File Share using a SAS token and AD authentication?

Comment: The file share is ad joined and the AAD and AD user object exists in both ad's

Comment: Share the script on how you are mounting a file share on a hybrid-joined machine?

Comment: $connectTestResult = Test-NetConnection -ComputerName xxxx.file.core.windows.net -Port 445
if ($connectTestResult.TcpTestSucceeded) {
    # Mount the drive
    New-PSDrive -Name Z -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\xxxx.file.core.windows.net\testjoin" -Persist
} else {
    Write-Error -Message "Unable to reach the Azure storage account via port 445. Check to make sure your organization or ISP is not blocking port 445, or use Azure P2S VPN, Azure S2S VPN, or Express Route to tunnel SMB traffic over a different port."
}

Comment: I don't want to mount it with the storage key for standard users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue and solved it by adding the host to realm.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-identity-auth-hybrid-identities-enable?tabs=azure-portal#configure-coexistence-with-storage-accounts-using-on-premises-ad-ds

```
ksetup /addhosttorealmmap <your storage account name>.file.core.windows.net DOMAIN
```